# How to use Cross Product Properites to do proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, vectors

How do I proceed with a proof for this question?

Prove that:
\begin{equation}
       (a \times  b) \cdot (c \times d)  =  \begin{vmatrix}
    a \cdot c & b \cdot c \\
    a \cdot d & b \cdot d \\
    \end{vmatrix} 
\end{equation}
I have to use the cross product properties to do the proof:
[image]

So far I have taken the det of the right side:

\begin{equation}
(a \times b) \cdot (c \times d) = (a \cdot c) \cdot (b\cdot d) - (b \cdot c)(a \cdot d) 
\end{equation}

I don't understand how to use the properities after this step.

Comment: So just what is your question for us?

Comment: How do I use the properties the do the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Property 5 states that:
$$\color{blue}{u}\cdot (\color{red}{v}\times\color{green}{w})=(\color{blue}{u}\times\color{red}{v})\cdot\color{green}{w}$$

Applying property 5 to the L.H.S. we get:

$\color{blue}{(a\times b)}\cdot (\color{red}{c}\times \color{green}{d}) = (\color{blue}{(a\times b)}\times \color{red}{c})\cdot \color{green}{d}$

Property 1 states that:

$$\color{blue}{u}\times \color{red}{v}=\color{red}{-v}\times\color{blue}{u}$$

So, applying property 1 to our previous step:

$(\color{blue}{(a\times b)}\times \color{red}{c})\cdot \color{green}{d}=(\color{red}{-c}\times \color{blue}{(a\times b)})\cdot \color{green}{d}$

Now that we have something of the form $u\times (v\times w)$, we can use property 6.

Continue the problem using property 6 to get rid of the $\times$ products in the expression and replace it with dot products, addition, and subtraction.  Continue simplifying to get to the result.

---

Property 6 states that:

$$\color{blue}{u}\times(\color{red}{v}\times\color{green}{w})=(\color{blue}{u}\cdot\color{green}{w})\color{red}{v}-(\color{blue}{u}\cdot\color{red}{v})\color{green}{w}$$

Using prop6 should only affect what is inside of the black parenthesis that I have written previously.

$=(\color{blue}{-c}\times (\color{red}{a}\times\color{green}{b}))\cdot d = ((\color{blue}{-c}\cdot\color{green}{b})\color{red}{a}-(\color{blue}{-c}\cdot\color{red}{a})\color{green}{b})\cdot d$

Comment: So, when I use property 6 I get: (a $\cdot$ c)b-(b $\ cdot$ c)d = (-c $\cdot$  a)b-(-c $\cdot$ b)d is this correct?

Comment: @Zero next step added.  Don't get confused by the fact that the properties use "a,b,c" and you also use "a,b,c" in your problem.  They might not be in the same order in the problem as they are in the property.  That is why I have opted to use colors, to make it clear where each piece goes.  It shouldn't be thought of as "a,b,c" in the properties so much as "first one, second one, third one."

Comment: ok, thanks the coloring really helps.

Comment: @Zero You can always add zero or multiply by one and not change anything.  If you "multiply by $-1$", you will have changed something.  You can however *factor out* a negative 1, i.e. use the fact that $-c = (-1)c$.  Remember that for dot product, $(\alpha u)\cdot (\beta v) = \alpha\beta (u\cdot v)$ (where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars) and that $u\cdot (v + w) = (u\cdot v) + (u\cdot w)$ as well as $(u+v)\cdot w = u\cdot w + v\cdot w$.  (I.e. that the dot product is bilinear)

Answer (score 0):

Using property 5, we get $(a \times  b) \cdot (c \times d) = ((a \times  b) \times c) \cdot d$. Then use property 1 to get $((a \times  b) \times c) \cdot d = (-c \times (a \times  b)) \cdot d$. Now we can apply property 6 to get $(-c \times (a \times  b)) \cdot d = -((c\cdot b)a-(c\cdot a)b)\cdot d$. If you simplify this expression using linearity of the dot product, you should get your expansion for the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(\vec a\times \vec b)\cdot(\vec c\times \vec d)&=((\vec a\times \vec b)\times \vec c)\cdot \vec d \tag 1 \\\\
&=(-\vec c\times (\vec a\times \vec b))\cdot \vec d \tag 2 \\\\
&=((\vec c\cdot \vec a)\vec b-(\vec c\cdot \vec b)\vec a)\cdot \vec d\tag 3\\\\
&=(\vec c\cdot \vec a)(\vec b\cdot \vec d)-(\vec c\cdot \vec b)(\vec a\cdot \vec d)
\end{align}$$

To arrive at $(1)$, we used Property $5$

To go from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used Property $1$

To go from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used Property $6$

Answer (score 0):

from the 5th property we have: $(a\times b).(c\times d)=((a\times b)\times c).d$
then from the 1th property: $((a\times b)\times c).d=-(c\times (a\times b)).d$
then from the 6th property:$-(c\times (a\times b)).d=-((c.b)a-(c.a)b).d$
so:
$$\begin{align}(a\times b).(c\times d)&=((a\times b)\times c).d\\
                                      &=-(c\times (a\times b)).d\\
                                      &=-((c.b)a-(c.a)b).d\\
                                      &=-((c.b)(a.d)-(c.a)(b.d))\\                         &=((c.a)(b.d)-(c.b)(a.d))\\                         &=(a.c)(b.d)-(b.c)(a.d)\\                          &=\begin{vmatrix}a.c & b.c\\                                                  a.d & b.d\end{vmatrix}\end{align}$$